# Javascript: get time taken to display. (Currently understated)

Tags: javascript, performance, timing

I'm using Javascript to run a simulation. While performance tuning I noticed that my timing code understates the execution time for displaying in the UI.

It's basically a couple of for-loops which collects data in a 2D array then outputs that to a HTML table. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m5wTW/). I'm running the code in Firefox.

Is there some sort of handler I can attach to an event that only fires once Firefox has finished updating the page? It seems that calling `new Date().getTime()` directly after `$('#div').html(theTable)` is not recording the time that Firefox actually finishes displaying the table.

My code basically amounts to this:

```
// CODE BLOCK 1: PROCESSING
var time1 = new Date().getTime();
// for loops here
// ....
time1 = new Date().getTime() - time1;

// CODE BLOCK 2: DISPLAYING
var time2 = new Date().getTime();
// create table here by string concatenation
// then inserting table html string into a div 
// with JQuery's element.html(...) method
// ....
time2 = new Date().getTime() - time2;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at ´console.time´ and ´console.timeEnd´, perhaps they may be of use to you, if you just need to log and view.

Comment: Very odd. I added the console timing calls. Now both ways seem to give an accurate time! Thank you